# How to take line from recent commit with Magit

Tags: magit, git

1. Use Magit to view the log with show diffs (`-p`).
2. Inspect 4 commit old commit.
3. Navigate to a few lines I've since deleted, but want back my project.

I can mark the lines but cannot copy them, which would be a sufficient solution for me. But, since we're opening the discussion, is there a better way to do this using Magit?

Comment: You should be able to `magit-diff-visit-file` on the diff (`RET` in spacemacs), or to be able to copy text, `evil-magit-toggle-text-mode` (`C-t` in spacemacs)

Comment: What about pure emacs?

Comment: You mean what key bindings?  Try e.g. `C-h f magit-diff-visit-file <RET>`, or look at the magit documentation (it says it's bound to `RET`, in fact)?  If you're not using evil and want to copy/paste, not sure, sorry -- in a pinch you could just `M-x text-mode <RET>` (you'll probably have to `C-x k` the magit buffer after that to make it work again).  Actually I think even if you're using evil, `evil-magit-toggle-text-mode` will have moved to evil-collection out of evil-magit very recently, and might be renamed with a new prefix there.